# Ruby http, net/http, httpclient: can't parse www.victoriassecret.com

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2

I am using `httpclient` gem, it works fine on Windows, just moved to **AWS EC2**, tried it on https://victoriassecret.com and it gets this response:

```
= Response

HTTP/1.1 920 Unknown
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 21:42:51 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 23

<h1>File not found</h1>#<HTTP::Message:0x000000023f5168
 @http_body=
  #<HTTP::Message::Body:0x000000023f50a0
   @body="<h1>File not found</h1>",
   @chunk_size=nil,
   @positions=nil,
   @size=0>,
 @http_header=
  #<HTTP::Message::Headers:0x000000023f5140
   @body_charset=nil,
   @body_date=nil,
   @body_encoding=#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>,
   @body_size=0,
   @body_type=nil,
   @chunked=false,
   @dumped=false,
   @header_item=
    [["Content-Type", "text/html"],
     ["Date", "Wed, 21 Oct 2015 21:42:51 GMT"],
     ["Connection", "Keep-Alive"],
     ["Content-Length", "23"]],
   @http_version="1.1",
   @is_request=false,
   @reason_phrase="Unknown",
   @request_absolute_uri=nil,
   @request_method="GET",
   @request_query=nil,
   @request_uri=
    #<URI::HTTPS:0x000000023f58c0 URL:https://www.victoriassecret.com/pink/new-and-now>,
   @status_code=920>,
 @peer_cert=
  #<OpenSSL::X509::Certificate: subject=#<OpenSSL::X509::Name:0x000000024ebe00>, issuer=#<OpenSSL::X509::Name:0x000000024ebec8>, serial=#<OpenSSL::BN:0x000000024de110>, not_before=2015-05-27 00:00:00 UTC, not_after=2017-05-26 23:59:59 UTC>,
 @previous=nil>
```

It does not work only with this website, `httpclient get https://google.com` for example works fine. But on Windows I get normal response from `httpclient get https://www.victoriassecret.com`. Butt when using standard NET/HTTP library I get the same 920 response on Windows.

Comment: On Mac OSX 10.10.2, I get `= Response

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 21:56:13 GMT
Location: https://www.victoriassecret.com/
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0`

Comment: Try making request to https://www.victoriassecret.com , not https://victoriassecret.com

Comment: But on Windows I can do this. Gem 'http' does not work too

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out, im seeing it from ec2 aswell but works ok on mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't ec2 related. It's most likely related to the User Agent header sent by the various http library implementations.

For example, they clearly don't like 'wget':

```
curl -A "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"  -v https://www.victoriassecret.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.victoriassecret.com/
*   Trying 98.158.54.100...
* Connected to www.victoriassecret.com (98.158.54.100) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 # truncated
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.victoriassecret.com
> User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 910 Unknown
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Thu, 22 Oct 2015 01:16:31 GMT
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 23
<
* Connection #0 to host www.victoriassecret.com left intact
<h1>File not found</h1>%
```

Comment: Nope, this isn't the case for this particular site. Trying it with latest Chrome user-agent on ec2, still get the weird 910 status code: curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36" -I -L https://www.victoriassecret.com/
HTTP/1.1 910 Unknown
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Fri, 15 Apr 2016 00:13:13 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0